# How do I trigger change on nested models in backbone-associations?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-associations

I have an employee model who has address model with 1-1 relationship. I would like to let Employee model know if some change occurs in Address which in turn is being listened by view.

```
 var Employee = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
        relations: [
            {
                type: Backbone.One, //nature of the relationship
                key: 'manager', // attribute of Employee
                relatedModel: 'Manager' //AssociatedModel for attribute key
            }
        ],
        defaults: {
            age : 0,
            fname : "",
            lname : "",
            manager : null
        }
    });

    var Manager = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
    });

    var EmployeeView = Backbone.View.extend({

      initialize: function(){
        this.model = new Employee();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'nested-change', this.render);
      }
    });
```

'nested-change' does not work when some change happens to Manager. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Backbone.Associations.EVENTS_NC = true;`

They have changed the default behavior in [version 0.6.0](https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-version-060---diff)